# How to prevent CSRF in AEM web application

Tags: csrf, aem, csrf-protection

We have CSRF issue reported in our web application with mutiple forms in the application. Our application is running on front end (AEM), and we have sso layer for single sign in using SAML and we also have seperate database layer, which they expose all the data's via web services and AEM will consumer the same for displaying and updating the data. If we have to implement CSRF token in AEM on all ajax requests like below, How this needs to be handled at DB level. Where do we get the CSRF token from which layer.

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, _, xhr) {
if ( !xhr.crossDomain ) 
xhr.setRequestHeader(CSRF_HEADER, securityToken);
});
```

Comment: Hard to post this as an answer, as the documentation is badly lacking, but this may be a good starting point for investigation: [CSRF Protection Framework](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/security/csrf-protection.html)

Comment: Are you using the buildin jquery library or did you package a different version with you code?

Comment: Hi Thomas, we are not sure how to implement this on AEM. we are not using any jquery library here as we are yet to implement

Comment: Which version of AEM are you using?

Comment: Hi @GauravSachdeva  We are using AEM 6.0

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take a guess at your application architecture as this. 
AEM Web App **--->** Webservice Hosting App **--->** DB.

Additionally, there is an IDP for SAML based authentication. Post the SSO authentication, all the interactions of the user is with the AEM web app.

Assuming the above, I'll say this is a regular AEM website. You can use OOTB AEM CSRF protection documented [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/csrf-protection.html).